# ACPI BIOS Error, root file system issue, and Bluetooth problem on HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec2xxx

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, hp

I'm currently facing some issues with my HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec2xxx running Ubuntu. I hope someone here can provide some guidance or solutions to help me resolve these problems. Here are the details:

```
ACPI BIOS Error:
    I encountered an ACPI BIOS Error with the message: "Failure creating named object [SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA], AE ALREADY EXISTS."
    Additionally, there was another error: "Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.GPPO.HDAU], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS."
    These errors appeared during boot and I'm unsure about their impact or how to resolve them.

Root file system issue:
    I received an error message stating: "Gave up waiting for root file system device."
    The error further suggested checking root delay and the existence of certain modules.
    Finally, it dropped me to a shell with the BusyBox environment.

Bluetooth problem:
    My Bluetooth functionality is also not working as expected.
    I encountered the error: "Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)."
```

I've already tried some basic troubleshooting steps such as restarting the system, enabling the wireless adapter, and checking physical switches. I also updated Ubuntu and checked for additional drivers, but the issues persist.

My system details:

```
Model: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec2xxx
Operating System: Ubuntu
```

If anyone has encountered similar problems or has any suggestions on how to fix these issues, I would greatly appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You've provided few specifics; what Ubuntu product? what release of that *unstated* Ubuntu product?  You mention it *gave up waiting for a device* but no specifics as to the actual message & what device(s) you have (was it a UUID? what UUID's do you have? have you made changes? as these messages are the result of changes or user-behavior or loss-of-power & the system requires user-behavior to fix; eg. after unclean shutdown I suggest performing file-system checks & after that expect normal operation but you gave no specifics)

Comment: You've stated three separate questions about what's wrong on your system.  Ask Ubuntu requires you to ask *one question* not four, and is not a Discussion Forum, so you need to pick one question and start there.